# Take keyword from URL PHP

Tags: php, url, post, keyword

I'm gonna explain everything.

So I managed to code a script that fills the POST form for you, and now when the form fills and the user logs in, they get a special key, I want to obtain this special key from the URL, let's say the URL is.

> script.php?key=1145682c3e7060514f57530c284f9ae3

This key will be changed every time the user logs in.

I hope I explained correctly.

Thanks!

PS. Script.php isn't hosted at my server, the script that auto fills the form is hosted at my server. I basically want it to auto fill the form (already finished that) then takes the key.

There's a login form ON A WEBSERVER THATS NOT MINE, after you login you get a key in the URL bar. I coded a script hosted ON MY WEBSERVER to go to that form and auto fill it using cURL, I need to make MY SCRIPT to obtain the key from the URL bar.

Comment: why can't you use $_GET["key"]?

Comment: Script.php isn't hosted at my server, the script that auto fills the form is hosted at my server.

Comment: `echo explode('=', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY))[1];`

Comment: How do you have access to the key? through the address bar or is the url just a string?

Comment: You need to delete this post, and start a new one, carefully explaining the entire setup in detail from the start.

Comment: Uh, lemme try to explain this again. There's a login form ON A WEBSERVER THATS NOT MINE, after you login you get a key in the URL bar. I coded a script hosted ON MY WEBSERVER to go to that form and auto fill it using cURL, I need to make MY SCRIPT to obtain the key from the URL bar.

Comment: @mirabilos It won't let me delete the post. :/

Comment: You don't have to delete it, you can just edit it. And don't forget to add your code.

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20788756/1607528

Comment: It sounds like the original form is sending a redirect. You need to use `cURL` to get the URL that the form is redirecting to.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly! How do I use cURL to obtain the URL?<3

Comment: Now that you've explained the question correctly, I found a duplicate question that should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value from the querystring using this:

```
$key = isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : null;
```

If it was posted:

```
$key = isset($_POST['key']) ? $_POST['key'] : null;
```

Check it by doing:

```
if ($key) {
    // do something here something          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the superglobal $_GET variable like:

```
$_GET['key']
```